# How do I get this template class to compile for Classes and primitive types?

Tags: c++, templates

How do I get the following code to compile?

I realize that the compiler is not happy with `V<double>` because it tries to compile my typedef for `GetterFn`, but I would like `GetterFn` and `GetCalc()` to be **available for classes, but ignored for primitive types.**

How should I recode this class?

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bar
{
    public:
        float getMyFloat() const { return 42.5; }
};

template< typename T >
class V
{
    public:
        typedef float (T::*GetterFn)() const;
        void getCalc( std::vector<double>& vec, GetterFn fn ) const
        {
            vec.clear();
            for ( size_t i=0; i<m_v.size(); ++i )
                vec.push_back( m_v[ i ].*(fn)() );
        }

    private:
        vector<T> m_v;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    V<Bar>    vb;  // ok
    V<double> vd;  // compiler not happy
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to suggest the complete solution without knowing what you want to do for fundamental types. However, at the heart I suggest you employ the `std::is_fundamental` type trait.

If you want entire collections of member functions to exist only conditionally, then perhaps wrapping them into a member helper class is one idea:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

class Bar
{
public:
  float getMyFloat() const { return 42.5; }
};

template< typename T >
class V
{
private:

  static const bool m_primitive = std::is_fundamental<T>::value; // convenience

  template <bool B, typename U> struct Helper;

  template <typename U> struct Helper<false, U>
  {
    typedef float (T::*GetterFnType)() const;
    void getCalc(std::vector<double> & v1, std::vector<U> const & v2, GetterFnType f)
    {
      v1.clear();
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v2.size(); ++i)
        v1.push_back((v2[i].*f)());
    }
  };

public:

  // use Helper<m_primitive, T>::GetterFn and Helper<m_primitive, T>::getCalc() here

private:
  std::vector<T> m_v;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  V<Bar>    vb;  // ok
  V<double> vd;  // compiler also happy
}
```

You'll probably also have to do some `std::enable_if` in the actual implementation. If you post more details, we can elaborate.

If you're open to a broader redesign, Konrad's answer feels like the final result would be somewhat cleaner and simpler, but then again I'm all in favour of convoluted template voodoo :-)

Comment: I am trying your answer in a sandbox atm - I agree - I like Konrad's answer for its clarity, but I need that typedef to deal with a method pointer that I need to pass in (for classes only).  Essentially, I want classes to be able to pass in a method pointer to do some work inside the class.  Primitives shouldn't need to provide this pointer (as it doesn't make sense at all) and shouldn't even have the method.

Comment: @kfmfe04: I understand that part. What I don't know is what actual work your class does, and how that depends on whether `T` is fundamental or not. There'll have to be some sort of compile-time branching when you write those actual implementations.

Comment: class V is actually a much-simplified version of a Time-Series class that takes an index type and a data type.  The data type can be fundamental or non-fundamental.  For non-fundamentals, I would like to allow the caller to name the method to be invoked for filling out a vector of results (using private data members).  I do not want to let the caller to be concerned about internal implementation for the data.

Comment: @kfmfe04: Yes, sure. Well, good luck piecing it all together! Feel free to post again if you want advice on how to integrate this helper class into your actual code. I can imagine another `template<bool>` wrapper somewhere that performs the relevant dispatch, but I'm sure you'll figure something out.

Comment: all your questions have gotten me thinking that maybe I should provide a begin() and end() implementation so I can just use a lambda in conjunction with passing back a reference to each data member (let the lambda take a reference to the item and invoke the method itself).  This may be the easiest for this specific case, but I do appreciate your template-gymnastics!  It seems like yet-another-tricky-tool I can put into my C++ toolbox.  (type_traits was in the back of my mind when I was thinking about this problem initially - you showed me how to use it effectively)

Comment: @kfmfe04: If that's an option, then definitely go for it -- providing an abstract, general interface to a template class that can be used uniformly is far more versatile and elegant (think locality) than providing different specific implementations of *one* consumer. Good plan :-)

Answer (score 3):

Alf’s slightly snarky answer is indeed the easiest way. Instead of having the `GetterFn` be a member function pointer, just use an overloaded free function to get the value:

```
void getCalc( std::vector<double>& vec) const
{
    vec.clear();
    for ( size_t i=0; i<m_v.size(); ++i )
        vec.push_back( get_value(m_v[ i ]) );
}
```

and then just overload `get_value` appropriately:

```
double get_value(double value) { return value; }

double get_value(Bar value) { return value.getMyFloat(); }
```

Of course, a more descriptive name than `get_value` is highly recommended.

Comment: +1 I like your answer for conciseness and clarity, but Kerrek's answer also offers a little more for dealing with the method pointer typedef.

Answer (score 1):

A `double` cannot have a member function. Ergo, use a non-member function.

Comment: could you clarify your answer a bit? which function do you propose to be moved and where?